# Preservation of ui condition

Tags: stochastic-calculus, martingales, stochastic-analysis, local-martingales

I have a stopping time $\tau_n$ with $\mathbb{P}(\tau_n=\infty)\rightarrow 1$ for $n \to \infty $. With this stoppingtime $M^{\tau_n}$ is a uniformly integrable martingale.

I deduced that $M$ is a local martingale but does it still hold the the uniformly integrable condition?

Comment: Please, avoid using such acronyms with a so-limited range of validity : replace "ui" by "uniform integrability" : why not ui = unable intellectuals, ui = you and I ?